# Query to fetch row values (first_name & last_name) using foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

New to SQL and MySQL.

In the below table, I've a table of employees where emp_id is employee's ID & super_id is supervisor's employee ID. Here super_id is assigned as foreign key of employee table itself.

[image: employee Table]

Now I need to fetch a table with three columns: first_name (supervisor), last_name (supervisor) and Count of employees who are supervised by this employee.

For Example:

```
David     Wallace   3
Michael   Scott     3
Josh      Porter    2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a self-join:

```
select tsuper.first_name, tsuper.last_name, count(*)
from t join
     t tsuper
     on t.super_id = tsuper.emp_id
group by tsuper.first_name, tsuper.last_name;
```

Comment: SELECT e.emp_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, COUNT(e2.super_id)
FROM employee AS e, employee AS e2
WHERE e2.super_id = e.emp_id
GROUP BY e.first_name, e.last_name;

I used this command taking your answer as reference and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the edit and answer as well.

Howevever I didn't use JOIN specifically here, can you please explain what would be the difference

Comment: @TechLearner . . . You are using archaic syntax which has been superseded for decades by `JOIN`.  Learn SQL properly.